# pandas.read_table() misses first row

Tags: python, pandas, file-io

I am trying to extract xyz data using pandas.read_table(). The example input is:

```
    6
 i =     3231, time =      390.951, E =     -2300.2877174514
  O        25.8720962272       23.5487057768       25.9550094332
  H        26.7134918815       24.0996155532       25.8555927088
  H        25.8292636841       23.2306526549       26.9004259942
  O        36.9646620515       28.9501274283       25.1072617903
  H        37.8691423626       29.0116615687       25.5343998500
  H        36.2185832462       28.8942276136       25.7705056388
    6
 i =     3232, time =      391.072, E =     -2300.2946639751
  O        25.8723495329       23.5479993390       25.9555177002
  H        26.7142142389       24.1025173761       25.8565522557
  H        25.8306551175       23.2286729433       26.9006241724
  O        36.9645963995       28.9502158930       25.1069529796
  H        37.8719573287       29.0104227338       25.5340553516
  H        36.2186719315       28.8940372004       25.7719527369
    6
 i =     3233, time =      391.193, E =     -2300.3008277490
  O        25.8725995056       23.5472934823       25.9560188995
  H        26.7150201443       24.1054166977       25.8575713111
  H        25.8320275873       23.2266501926       26.9008810031
  O        36.9645310733       28.9503042170       25.1066361406
  H        37.8748229967       29.0091775522       25.5337615585
  H        36.2187349648       28.8938586630       25.7734429616
```

and my MWE is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

count_steps=0
n_atoms=6
with open("./test.xyz",'r') as inputfile:
     for data_file in inputfile:
         for i in range(0, n_atoms):
             molecule = pd.read_table(inputfile, comment='#', skiprows=2, nrows=n_atoms, delim_whitespace=True, names=['atom', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
             count_steps += 1
             print(molecule)
inputfile.close()
```

The XYZ format is:

```
<number of atoms>
comment line
<element> <X> <Y> <Z>
...
```

So I skip the first two lines and read the rest of the data according to the number of atoms. While running the above snippet I noticed that I missing the first row (i.e., the third row in the input) in the output:

```
  atom          x          y          z
0    H  26.713492  24.099616  25.855593
1    H  25.829264  23.230653  26.900426
2    O  36.964662  28.950127  25.107262
3    H  37.869142  29.011662  25.534400
4    H  36.218583  28.894228  25.770506
5    6        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

which I am cannot figure out. Is there is a read_table() parameter I am missing or is it some sort of formatting issue?

Comment: `for data_file in inputfile:` reads a line from the file into the `data_file` variable every time it iterates. That line won't be read by `pd.read_table`.

Comment: @Barmar What if I have loop through the entire input while using a smaller dataframe to extract data? In my understanding I have to loop over entire file...

Comment: Use `skiprows=1` because you already skipped a line by reading it with `for`.

Comment: `for data_file in inputfile` reads a line from the file, that seems wrong, don't do that. Let read_table be the only thing that reads from the file?

Comment: @creanion Then is there a way to loop over the file and extract contents into pd.DataFrame()?

Comment: You need to make a loop without iterating over the file.

The inputfile loop reads lines of the the file. Is that what you want? It doesn't seem like it to me. Maybe break it down in basic operations to see what it is doing. The file object is stateful. You open it and it has a cursor at the start of the file. Everything you read from the file moves the cursor forward - that includes the `for data_file` loop and it includes `read_table` that also reads from the *open file object*.  How do you think it works that each call to read_table reads a new atom? The file object's cursor.